# Bootstrap dropdown - different look-n-feel in IE9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I am using bootstrap css to rendering dropdown:
Following is the code:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
</select>
```

In IE9 the look-n-feel is different from other browser (especially the right hand side down-arrow).

Is there any way I can fix the issue in IE9 through css? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could find for your situation was a neat jQuery plugin that will style your select box for multiple browsers.

http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

According to their documentation they have tested in IE8+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 4+, and Opera 11+.

However through CSS it is going to be challenging task to keep consistent throughout all browsers.

Comment: Yes this works. But if you look at the source code, it is not changing actual select options. I mean select box has been replaced with <div><span>...</span></div>. There is no change in selected option in actual select box.

Comment: In just IE9 or are you saying any browser for this specific statement?

Comment: for any browser, it will apply display:none for <select..> and replace it with <div>, so whenever we change option, it just changes the <span> selection and not the <option>.